# DataList not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, sqldatasource, datalist

I've been stuck on this problem for hours now and I have literally tried everything but nothing works!

So I have this piece of code in my button click event:

```
 protected void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        string query;
        int make = System.Convert.ToInt32(make_list.SelectedValue);
        int model = System.Convert.ToInt32(model_list.SelectedValue);

        query = "SELECT c.owner_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, City.city, Makes.make, Models.model, Type.type, Colours.colour, [Year].[year], c.price, c.photo1, c.photo2, c.photo3, c.ID AS carID FROM (((((((Cars c INNER JOIN Users u ON c.owner_id = u.ID) INNER JOIN City ON u.city_id = City.ID) INNER JOIN Models ON c.model_id = Models.ID) INNER JOIN Makes ON Models.make_id = Makes.ID) INNER JOIN Type ON Models.type_id = Type.ID) INNER JOIN Colours ON c.colour_id = Colours.ID) INNER JOIN [Year] ON c.year_id = [Year].ID) WHERE ";

        if (make != 1)
        {
            query = query + "Models.make_id = @make";
            SearchDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("make", make.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            query = query + "Models.make_id > 0";
        }

        if (model != 1)
        {
            query = query + " AND c.model_id = @model";
            SearchDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("model", model.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            query = query + " AND c.model_id > 0";
        }


     SearchDataSource.SelectCommand = query;
     DataList1.DataBind();

 }
```

So the query checks from the Cars table whether a certain car exists depending on the users input on the dropdown lists whilst joining the relevant tables together to get the result I want. In my cars table only 1 car exists with the make of "Alfa Romeo" and the model of "4C".

In my XAML I have:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SearchDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\4WheelsDB.mdb;Persist Security Info=True" ProviderName="System.Data.OleDb">
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SearchDataSource">
      <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblmake_id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("make") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

So when I test this query out in Access with the make value of 2 which is Alfa Romeo and the Model value of 2 which is 4C it returns 1 row which is perfect. And when I test Alfa Romeo with the Model value of 3 which is Giuletta it returns no rows which is also perfect.

So since their is nothing wrong with the query, its time to test how it is on the website, when testing it out on the website I select Alfa Romeo 4C and it shows the make in the item list, however when I select Alfa Romeo Giuletta it still shows the make in the item list, but when I reload the whole page and select Alfa Romeo Giuletta it shows nothing and when I select Alfa Romeo 4C it shows nothing again!

So it seems that I have to refresh the page to show the result which is expected, I honestly dont know why it is doing this but I have tried Disposing then DataBinding the DataList before anything else in the Click even however nothing works!

Does anyone know what the problem is? If you need me to explain further more please ask, thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75123/discussion-on-question-by-c0mrade-datalist-not-updating).

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

AFTER:
SearchDataSource.SelectCommand = query;

ADD:
DataList1.Databind()

Comment: I've tried that before, sorry for not saying.. but yeah, it doesn't work :/